# using rvest to create a data.frame

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm learning how to scrape a website using rvest and I get the following output after running the code below:

```
p<-read_html("https://example.com") %>%
html_text()
p
```

> [1] "window.location = "https://example.com" Submission Information:
> Name:\n\t\t\t\t\t Jon Doe City:\n\t\t\t\t\t Milwaukee
> State:\n\t\t\t\t\t WI Zip:\n\t\t\t\t\t 53045 Car Information: Date
> Bought:\n\t\t\t\t\t 07/13/1999 Time:\n\t\t\t\t\t 8 pm
> Brand:\n\t\t\t\t\t Ford Color:\n\t\t\t\t\t Blue

I would like to create a dataset (data.frame?) that include the following information (this would just the first row):

| Name | City | State | Zip | Date Bought | Time | Brand | Color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jon Doe | Milwaukee | WI | 53045 | 09/13/1999 | 8 pm | Ford | Blue |

Notice that I removed things like `"window.location = \"https://example.com"`, `Submission Information:`, `Car Information:`, and `\n\t\t\t\t\t` from the above. How would I do this in R after I have this text output from scraping with rvest?

This is not a public site so I can't share the actual link - it requires authenticated access which I've figured out.  But I was able to grab a sample of the basic page that I am trying to scrape.  I essentially want a table with all information below, minus Member Information, Car Information, Dealer Information, Buyer Information, and Insurance Information, since those labels just identify sections, which I don't need for the data set.

```
<tr><td><span style="color:#ffb76b;"> Member Information:</span></td><br />
<td><span style="margin-left:145px; color:white;"> Name:</span></td>
<td><span style="color:white; padding-left:100px;"> John Doe</span></td><br /><td><span style="margin-left:145px; color:white;"> City:</span></td>
<td><span style="color:white; padding-left:112px;"> Milwaukee</span></td><br /><td><span style="margin-left:145px; color:white;"> State:</span></td>
<td><span style="color:white; padding-left:107px;"> WI</span></td><br /><td><span style="margin-left:145px; color:white;"> Zip:</span></td>
<td><span style="color:white; padding-left:118px;"> 53045</span></td><br /><td><span style="margin-left:145px; color:white;"> Angler Class:</span></td>
<td><span style="color:white; padding-left:62px;"> Male</span></td><br /><td><span style="color:#ffb76b"> Car Information:</span></td><br />
<td><span style="margin-left:145px; color:white;"> Date Bought:</span></td>
<td><span style="color:#ffb76b; padding-left:62px;"> 09/13/1999</span></td><br /><td><span style="margin-left:145px; color:white;"> Time:</span></td>
<td><span style="color:white; padding-left:107px;"> 8 pm</span></td><br /><td><span style="margin-left:145px; color:white;"> Length:</span></td>
<td><span style="color:white; padding-left:97px;"> 16ft</span></td><br /><td><span style="margin-left:145px; color:white;"> Weight:</span></td>
<td><span style="color:white; padding-left:95px;"> Not Specified</span></td><br /><td><span style="margin-left:145px; color:white;"> Tire:</span></td>
<td><span style="color:white; padding-left:108px;"> Not Specified</span></td><br /><td><span style="margin-left:145px; color:white;"> Age:</span></td>
<td><span style="color:white; padding-left:72px;"> 20 years</span></td><br /><td><span style="margin-left:145px; color:white;"> Mileage:</span></td>
<td><span style="color:white; padding-left:67px;"> 65,305</span></td><br /><td><span style="margin-left:145px; color:white;"> Damage:</span></td>
<td><span style="color:white; padding-left:58px;"> None</span></td><br /><td><span style="margin-left:145px; color:white;"> Model:</span></td>
<td><span style="color:white; padding-left:93px;"> Taurus</span></td><br /><td><span style="color:#ffb76b"> Dealer Information:</span></td><br />
<td><span style="margin-left:145px; color:white;"> Name:</span></td>
<td><span style="color:white; padding-left:114px;"> ABC Auto</span></td><br /><td><span style="margin-left:145px; color:white;"> Zip:</span></td>
<td><span style="color:white; padding-left:47px;"> 15101</span></td><br /><td><span style="margin-left:145px; color:white;"> Rating:</span></td>
<td><span style="color:white; padding-left:63px;"> 5</span></td><br /><td><span style="color:#ffb76b"> Buyer Information:</span></td><br />
<td><span style="margin-left:145px; color:white;"> Sales Person:</span></td>
<td><span style="color:white; padding-left:66px;"> John Wick</span></td><br /><td><span style="margin-left:145px; color:white;"> County:</span></td>
<td><span style="color:white; padding-left:94px;"> Waukesha</span></td><br /><td><span style="margin-left:145px; color:white;"> State:</span></td>
<td><span style="color:white; padding-left:107px;"> Wisconsin</span></td><br /><td><span style="margin-left:145px; color:white;"> Rating:</span></td>
<td><span style="color:white; padding-left:58px;"> Good</span></td><br /><td><span style="margin-left:145px; color:white;"> Experience:</span></td>
<td><span style="color:white; padding-left:83px;"> Not Specified</span></td><br /><td><span style="color:#ffb76b"> Insurance Information:</span></td><br />
<td><span style="margin-left:145px; color:white;"> Insurer Name:</span></td>
<td><span style="color:white; padding-left:68px;"> Allstate</span></td><br /><td><span style="margin-left:145px; color:white;"> Primary Coverage:</span></td>
<td><span style="color:white; padding-left:52px;"> Tier3</span></td><br /><td><span style="margin-left:145px; color:white;"> Secondary Coverage:</span></td>
<td><span style="color:white; padding-left:34px;"> Not Specified</span></td><br /><td><span style="margin-left:145px; color:white;"> Policy Period:</span></td>
<td><span style="color:white; padding-left:64px;"> 2019</span></td><br /></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data <-  read_html("https://example.com")

html_nodes(data, "table") %>% 
  html_table()
```

https://fahimahmad.netlify.app/posts/scraping-html-tables-into-r-data-frames/

Comment: doing this just returns  "list()" in the console and not any of the scraped data.  Perhaps I missed something?